# Using results from a query as my query search criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Sever 2008. I have several WHERE statements stored in the database. I am trying to build a query using the query criteria in the table.

So let's say I had a table called 'Categories'

```
+----------+------------------------+  
| Seq | SQLWHERE          
+----------+------------------------+  
|        0 | ([ID] >= 60010   
|        1 | And                      
|        2 | [ID] <= 60020)   
|        3 | Or                       
|        4 | [ID] = 60025     
|        5 |  Or                      
|        6 | [ID] = 60035)   
+----------+------------------------+
```

So in essence i would need to build a query that used the SQLWHERE lines above in order of sequence 0-6.

So I'd need something to the effect below, but this does not work.

```
SELECT *
FROM AnotherTable
WHERE (SELECT SQLWHERE FROM Categories ORDER BY Seq)
```

because I would want to SQL query to render

```
SELECT *
FROM AnotherTable
WHERE  
([ID] >= 60010   
And                      
[ID] <= 60020)   
Or                       
[ID] = 60025     
Or                      
[ID] = 60035)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to create a function or stored procedure to query the where items and build the SQL dynamically. Then execute the SQL with your attached where clauses.  Here is a stored proc example.  Change "AnotherTable" to your table name and change CategoryX to Category.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExecutDynamicWhere
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Where VARCHAR(8000)  
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)  

    SELECT @Where = COALESCE(@Where + ' ', '') + SQLWhere From CategoryX

    Set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE ' + @Where

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert every row in a string [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

and pass it to [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)